# How to access received JSON data from Flask Template?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

**1.**
In this example code when you click on a date a JSON string is sent to my Flask view.

**2.**
In Flask view (ajax.py) I then plan on doing some more advanced processing but for now I just return the same JSON data with an extra message and only returning the 4th item from the list key.

**3.**
The third stage where Flask view is sending the JSON data back to Flask template is where I'm having problems. I don't really understand how to access the JSON data from my Flask template?

When using Chrome's console mode:

```
* Network > XHR > Response
```

I see that I have received this data in console mode, but how do I access these values from my Flask template file?:

```
{
  "age": 35, 
  "full_date": "2019-07-18", 
  "location": "United States", 
  "name": "Anthony", 
  "randomkeyinlist": "four", 
  "result": "Success!"
}
```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def ajax():
    return render_template('ajax.html')

@app.route('/_get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    # dictionary
    data = request.get_json()

    full_date = data['full_date']
    name = data['name']
    age = data['age']
    location = data['location']
    randomlist = data['randomlist']

    return jsonify({'result': 'Success!',
                    'full_date': full_date,
                    'name': name,
                    'age': age,
                    'location': location,
                    'randomkeyinlist': randomlist[3]
    })
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JSON Flask AJAX</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- _______________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
integrity="sha384-TlQc6091kl7Au04dPgLW7WK3iey+qO8dAi/LdwxaGBbszLxnizZ4xjPyNrEf+aQt"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- _______________________________________________________________________ -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

  //----------------------------------//
 //  jQuery UI Datepicker: Settings  //
//----------------------------------//
$('#inlineDate').datepicker({
    altField: "#demoDate",
    showOtherMonths: true
});

  //----------------------------------------//
 //  jQuery UI Datepicker: getDate method  //
//----------------------------------------//
$('#inlineDate').change(function() {
    "use strict";
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var $fullDate;

    $fullDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

      //--------//
     //  AJAX  //
    //--------//
    const toSend = {
        full_date: $fullDate,
        name: "Anthony",
        age: 35,
        location: "United States",
        randomlist: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    };

    // Convert js value to JSON string.
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
    console.log(jsonString);

    // Create XMLHttpRequest object.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Send HttpRequest to web server.
    xhr.open("POST", "/_get_data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(jsonString);

}); // END getDate method

}); // END .ready event
</script>

<!-- _______________________________________________________________________ -->

<style>
th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<!-- jQuery UI DatePicker Widget -->
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div id="wrapper" class="ui-widget">
    <label for="demoDate">Date: </label><input id="demoDate"/><span id="inlineDate"></span>
    </div>
</form>

<br>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Task</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Check</td>
        <td>Receive JSON data from Flask view.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>How?</td>
        <td>Access received JSON data in Template.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to state response handler using onstatechange check out example here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Is it the code example from this chapter that I need to focus on? https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlfile.asp
I'm not very familiar using AJAX so I get lost very easily when they didn't show any examples using Python and Flask framework.